# Calculate Difference between two datetime values in CosmosDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Let's say we have documents with an EffectiveDate DateTime field.  How do you query CosmosDb to return records where the difference between today and EffectiveDate is greater than 30?

This doesnt appear to work:

```
select c from c where ("2020-01-28T00:00:00-06:00" - c.effectiveDate) > 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to refer to the offical document [`User-defined functions (UDFs) in Azure Cosmos DB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs) to know the feature `UDF` of Azure CosmosDB, and you can use it to realize your needs.

As the figure below, follow the steps to create an UDF named `utctime` using JavaScript in Data Explorer of Azure CosmosDB on Azure portal.

[image]

```
function userDefinedFunction(dateStr){
    return new Date(dateStr).getTime() / 1000;
}
```

Then, you can do the SQL query as you wish as below.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE (udf.utctime('2020-01-28T00:10:00-06:00') - udf.utctime(c.effectiveDate)) > 30
```

The result of my sample as the figure below.

[image]

Comment: what does the divide by 1000 indicate?

Comment: @obautista Just for converting milliseconds to seconds.